# What is actual difference between transitivity and quasitransitivity?

Tags: relations, order-theory

I have been trying to construct q.t. relation, but always get transitive relation.

It seems to me, that transitivity includes q.t. Ok, but how would look like pure q.t. relation?

Examples and definitions seem to me ( in my opinion, which might be wrong) to contracict each other.

Here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasitransitive_relation I cant belp myself but it seems to me there is contradiction in definition and example given in properties. Further search on the internet didnt clear it up for me.

Please give me explicit examples.

Thank you all kindly.

Comment: From the wiki on QT, it gives the example: "The classic example is a person indifferent between 7 and 8 grams of sugar and indifferent between 8 and 9 grams of sugar, but who prefers 9 grams of sugar to 7 [...] The relation from the above sugar example, $\{(7,7), (7,8), (7,9), (8,7), (8,8), (8,9), (9,8), (9,9)\}$, is quasitransitive, but not transitive."

Comment: There is conflict in my opinion with their definition. I know this example.

Comment: This dumb attitude really does not help. Less people like you would be appriciated. It did not help my trouble.

Comment: And I dont know how to type math stuff, not a programmer. I know I am not smartes person. But if smart people behave like this, then we have a serious problem.

Comment: @JosefHlava Comments are for critiquing the question, not the individual.

Comment: @bof To give some slack to the OP: for all they knew they might have thought, for example, that quasi-transitivity was such a well-known property of relations that it would not be necessary to repeat the definition in the question itself. Let's try to rectify the situation before downvoting, would you agree?

Comment: My profound apologies, Mr. Hlava. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with their example of people being indifferent between $7g$ and $8g$ of sugar, and also indifferent between $8g$ and $9g$ of sugar, but preferring $9g$ to $7g$? The relation on $X=\{7,8,9\}$ is given as $\le=\{(7,7),(7,8),(7,9),(8,7),(8,8),(8,9),(9,8),(9,9)\}=X^2\setminus\{(9,7)\}$. I will leave to you to prove that the implication in the definition of quasitransitivity:

$$(a\text{ T }b)\land\lnot(b\text{ T }a)\land(b\text{ T }c)\land\lnot(c\text{ T }b)\implies(a\text{ T }c)\land\lnot(c\text{ T }a)$$

is always true because the left side of it is always false (as the first two terms imply $a=7,b=9$ but the second two term imply $b=7,c=9$. However, the relation is not transitive as $9\le 8$ and $8\le 7$ but $9\not\le 7$.

Comment: What I dont understand is: 7R8 AND not 8R7. In given relation, there is 8,7. This confuses me. Because I know that AND is not true if at least one instance is not true. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Correct, so the left side of the implication is false, and so the implication itself is true.

Comment: Oh my!! Now this is how I am supposed to think about this? I did not consider false premise to make implication true. Just it seems quite weird to me. So by this token very many relations would be actually quasitransitive. If both sides are false - then relation is also quasitransitive... :D :D weird, but true in logic. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the relation $\approx$. To be concrete, consider $S = \{0, 1, 2\}$ with $a \approx b :\equiv (|a - b| \leq 1)$. Then $\approx$ is quasitransitive but not transitive.

Comment: So would relation |a-b| <1 OR |a-b| >1  on set {0, 1, 2} would be quasitransitive? First part of implication is false, so the whole implication is true? I presume yes :)

Comment: Yes. However, that relation also happens to be transitive, so it doesn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, so in the set {0, 1, 2, 3} transitivity would fail and now I have qu.tr. , because premise is false?

Comment: @JosefHlava You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are  3 quasitranitive relations for a set of 2 elements.

```
{(0, 1), (1, 0)}
{(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)}
{(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)}
```

There are  277 quasitranitive relations for a set of 3 elements.

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 2), (2, 0)]
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

These data was created with the following python program.

```
from  itertools import product, chain, combinations
NumberOfElements=3
def is_tranitive(rel):
    for triple in product(list(range(NumberOfElements)),repeat=3):
        if ((triple[0],triple[1]) in rel 
        and (triple[1],triple[2]) in rel 
        and not (triple[0],triple[2]) in rel):
            return False
    return True

def is_quasitranitive(rel):
    for triple in product(list(range(NumberOfElements)),repeat=3):
        if ((triple[0],triple[1]) in rel 
        and (triple[1],triple[0]) not in rel 
        and (triple[1],triple[2]) in rel 
        and (triple[2],triple[1]) not in rel 
        and  not((triple[0],triple[2]) in rel
        and (triple[2],triple[1]) not in rel)):
            return False
    return True


crossproduct=list(product(list(range(NumberOfElements)),repeat=2))
powerset=chain.from_iterable(combinations(crossproduct, r) for r in range(len(crossproduct)+1))
cnt_quasi=0
for x in powerset:
    y=set(x)
    if is_quasitranitive(y):
        if not is_tranitive(y):
            cnt_quasi+=1
            print(sorted(x))
print('There are ',cnt_quasi,'quasitranitive relations for a set of',NumberOfElements,'elements.')
```